# GCP Bigquery create autorized views by terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery, authorization, terraform

I have a specific question regarding the authorized views in Bigquery and terraform.

**Situation:** I have already created the simple terraform script to create some Bigquery datasets, tables, views and an IAM entries also. Especially, I create two datasets (`source_dataset` and `target_dataset`), some tables in the `source_dataset` and views in the `target_dataset`, which are based on the `source_database`. The clue is to use [Bigquery authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) to separate permissions - the views should be accessible by the group od viewers, which don't have an access to the original `source_dataset`, but are still able to query the views.

**Question: Is it possible to authorized the views from the terraform code?** When i try to use the terraform code, the chicken/egg issue emerge. I know, that it's possible to separate to build configuration - write some code in the terraform and authorize the views after that by the python code, but ideally would be to use 100% terraform only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the chicken and egg issue has been resolved on the upcoming release:

> [**bigquery dataset view access creates circular dependency #2686**](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/2686)

The problem as defined:

> The view can't be created because it depends on another dataset,
>   That other dataset can't be created because it depends on the view
>
> A circular dependency exists.

The resolution:

> Once it gets released (it should appear in version 3.17.0) it'll be usable as a google_bigquery_dataset_access resource. Here's a preview of what the docs page will look like: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/website/docs/r/bigquery_dataset_access.html.markdown

Comment: This does not work because the `access` for the authorized view is saved in the state of the dataset. So it works the 1st time, but if you apply again, tf will remove the access because it's in the dataset's state but not wanted by the config.